# binary search of sorted array in assembly language

Tags: assembly, binary-search

```
[org 0x100]
;This code is for counting the size 
        mov di, 0           ; to be used for indexing 
        mov bp, s_a
        mov cx, 0
        jmp count

j1:     inc cx              ; storing the size in cx
count:  mov ax, [bp+di] 
        add di, 2
        cmp ax, -1          ;-1 is the ending condition
        jne j1
;=================================;

        mov si, cx          ;Moving the size in si
        mov cx, 2           ;using cx for division number

;This code is for finding the centre point by division
j2:     mov ax, si
        mov bx, 0
        mov bx, cx
        div bl
;=================================;
        inc cx
        inc cx 
        cmp al, 0           ;If al has 0 then the number is not in array
        je nfound
        mov dl, al  
        mov di, 0

;Increasing bx to point to the required number
j3:     inc di
        inc di
        dec dx
        cmp dx, 0
        jne j3
;=================================;
        mov ax, [bp+di] ;Moving the centre number in array to ax
        mov dx, [b_s]       ;The number to be found

        cmp dx, ax
        je found            

        cmp dx, ax
        jl below

        cmp dx, ax
        jg above

above:  add bp, di
        jmp j2

below:  jmp j2

found:  mov cx, bp
        add cx, di
        jmp exit

nfound: mov ax, [bp]        ;This code is for the first element
        mov di, 0
        cmp ax, [b_s]
        je found            
        ;=================;
        mov cx, 0xffff
exit:

mov ax, 4c00h
int 21h

s_a: dw 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -1
b_s: dw 5
```

This is my code for binary search its working fine for all numbers here except for '1' and '5'. I have handled the for '1'. Please suggest a solution for '5' as well. which means last number. '-1' is not to be searched.

Comment: The default segment of using "bp" as an address register is the stack segment, but not the data segment. For to fix the code you can additional use a DS segment override prefix. Example: mov ax, DS:[bp+di]

Comment: Why are you using a very expensive instruction "div" where the equivalent "shr 1" would do?

Comment: When your code jumps back to the *j2* label it uses a CX value that is too high for *finding the centre point*. Always divide by 2, or shift right once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see some reasons why your code could fail.

- You assign a byte value to DL but later compare the word value in DX without making sure what DH contains.

  ```
  mov dl, al  
  mov di, 0
  ;Increasing bx to point to the required number
  j3:
  inc di
  inc di
  dec dx
  cmp dx, 0
  jne j3
  ```

  Either explicitely clear DH or decrement/compare only with DL.
- When the element was not found you simply jump back to label *j2*. This is wrong because you will be using the same number of elements contained in SI. You should recalculate the number of elements in the left/right partition. Either use (SI / 2) or (SI / 2 + 1)

Referring to the comment by Dirk Wolfgang Glomp

- Seeing `[org 0x100]` would mean that this is a .COM executable and so all segment registers should have the same value. Then there's no real need to write a DS: when using `[bp+di]`.

Please clean up your code

- Writing 2 `inc` instructions in a row should become `add ..., 2`
- There's no need to move zero in a register before loading it with another register. `mov bx, 0` `mov bx, cx`

Comment: About dx when debugger starts its value is already 0 but i cleared it as you said. but still same thing. And about si if i take jump on j1 then it will work the same right?

Comment: Simply changing `jmp j2` into `jmp j1` will not solve the problem. As an example at the lable _below:_ you need the following: `shr si,1` `mov cx,2` `jmp j2`